# Clarifying vulkan glsl std140

Tags: glsl, vulkan

So I have a uniform block that looks something lile this

{
mat4;
mat4[128];
uint[16]
}

The block should total up to 8320 bytes. After aligning by 256 bytes for nvidia, that brings the total allocation size to 8448 bytes.

However, according to renderdoc and spirv-cross the total block size should be 8512 bytea. Can someone explain to me why there is a 64 byte padding at the end?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The block should total up to 8320 bytes.

No, it shouldn't. You use a `uint[16]` array. Well, std140 layout makes it clear that the array stride for *any array* is always rounded up to the stride of a `vec4`. So that array takes up 256 bytes.

You should instead use a `uvec4[4]` instead, which you would index from like a multidimensional array.

Comment: Thanks! The vulkan spec doesn't clearly state the std140 rules and i must have missed that. Is this better  documented in the opengl spec instead? Or doea glsl have its own spec?

Comment: @Temp4890: "*The vulkan spec doesn't clearly state the std140 rules*" It isn't supposed to. `std140` layout is not a part of Vulkan or SPIR-V; it's a part of *OpenGL and GLSL*. Vulkan *requires* that the SPIR-V it consumes provides explicit byte offsets and array/matrix strides; it doesn't allow you to use `std140` layout. It is the GLSL-to-SPIR-V compiler that creates these offsets&strides by applying the OpenGL `std140` rules. It's GLSL/OpenGL that decides what `std140` means.

Comment: @Temp4890: That being said, the [Vulkan specification section on layout](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1/html/chap14.html#interfaces-resources) does make it clear that UBOs require that the ArrayStride must be a multiple of the size of the extended alignment. And the extended alignment of an array/struct is the alignment of its member(s), rounded up to 16.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'll go grab myself a copy of the glsl spec